# Middle Fucntion/Query for odd and even string

Tags: mysql

I need a single query which gives two middle characters of even string and one middle character of odd string.

Currently i am using this code but it is giving error.

```
SELECT S_name, MID(S_name, LENGTH(S_name)/2,1) WHERE (LENGTH(S_name) %2) = 1 OR/AND SELECT S_Name, MID(S_name,LENGTH(S_name)/2,2) WHERE (LENGTH(S_name)%2)=0 FROM Student;
```

I have also tried this code but it is returning empty view/table.

```
SELECT S_name FROM Student WHERE ((LENGTH(S_name) %2) = 1 AND SUBSTRING(S_name, LENGTH(S_name)/2+1, 1)) OR ((LENGTH(S_name) %2) = 0 AND SUBSTRING(S_name, LENGTH(S_name)/2-1, 2))
```

Please Just take a look at it and point out my mistake.

Comment: If you are getting an error, please post the error. See the [help/on-topic] about debugging help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `case` in the `select` clause:

```
select s_name,
       (case when length(s_name) % 2 = 0 then substring(s_name, length(s_name)/2, 2)
             else substring(s_name, 1 + length(s_name) / 2, 1)
        end)
from student;
```